# Jquery date rule not working in firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, firefox, jquery-validate

I have rendered the normal text with jquery date rule. The date rule working fine in chrome but not working in the Firefox and IE . please see my code block.

`<form id="myform">
  <input id="datepick" type="text" name ="datepick"/>

  <input type="submit" id="ValidateDate" />
</form>`

```
    $("#myform").validate({
         rules: {
           datepick:{
               date:"MM/dd/yyyy" 
           }    
      },
        messages: {
           datepick:{
             date:"Give MM/dd/yyyy format"
        }
     }
  });
    $('#datepick').keyup(function () {
        $("#ValidateDate").submit();
    });
</script>
```

when i type **12/3err/3001** it throws error in all browser

when i type **12/234/2333** it throws error chrome not in firefox and IE.

Additionally i want to share one information.

http://jqueryvalidation.org/date-method/

In the above link jQuery validation is not working properly in Mozilla , IE browser even for a normal textbox.

please type the **22/233/2222** value in the above jquery link sample then you can find the below output variation

In chrome :

[image: chrome output screen shot]

In Firefox:

[image]

Please help me to resolve this.....

Thanks,

Gobalakrishnan

Comment: What is the purpose of your `keyup` handler?  It does not make any sense since the validate plugin already evaluates all rules on every keyup event by default.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you've linked to says this:

> This method **should not be used**, since it relies on the new Date constructor, which **behaves very differently across browsers** and locales. Use `dateISO` instead or one of the locale specific methods (in localizations/ and additional-methods.js).

My emphasis.

Comment: But i have created a simple normal text box sample with date rule (above provided code block ). Its not working properly in Firefox and IE browser .. do u have any solution for this....please help me

Comment: @GopalaKrishnansubramanian please read what I posted. Your syntax is correct. The method you are using is flawed and does not work consistently across browsers as you are experiencing. You need to use `dateISO`.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is due to the date parsing behavior difference between the browsers. You can see the below.

Chrome

> new Date("92/12/2015")
>    - Invalid Date

FireFox

> new Date("92/12/2015")
>    - Date {Sun Jun 07 1998 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)}

The `date` rule will only check for format based on inputted date value and hence the validation succeeded in FF.

So as @SomekidwithHTML proposed you can use the `dateIso` which will check the date against ISO date standards or implement your our custom validation as per your need.

http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/